# malware classification based on action

Tags: malware

Where can I get info with a view to classify malware based on actions performed by the them. Eg. modifying registry files, copying themselves into other executable's etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean how to automatically classify malware, this paper on [Learning and Classification of Malware Behavior](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?cluster=7816310739819850281) ([Meta data](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1428330)) can be of help.

Answer (score 2):

A good site, formerly known as `cwsandbox.org` is now called [mwanalysis.org](http://mwanalysis.org).  Just submit a sample and it generates a behavioral report. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

For file and registry accesses, run it in a VM with Process Monitor running or upload it to [here.](http://anubis.iseclab.org/)

Answer (score 1):

enter the Malware name here [Threat Expert](http://www.threatexpert.com)
and you will get  a lot of useful info about that Malware

Answer (score -1):

you can use any API hooking application. Depends on which Ring that you want to hook.

Or Viking enough, write your own hook program.